# Deploy only cube schema, without processing

Tags: ssas

Is there a way to only deploy cube schema, but without processing the cube. It seems in Visual Studio, when yo deploy a cube, by default, it is "Deploy and Process".

The problem is processing takes so much time, and my main purpose is just writing some MDX script and see if it works well against the cube structure. It seems processing whole cube is just over kill. So I ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can programatically deploy just the MDX script.  There is also a download on Microsoft's web site called [BIDS helper](http://www.codeplex.com/bidshelper) that has a facility to do this.  It's a plugin for visual studio that provides various tools, including a facility to download a MDX script to a cube.

Answer (score 16):

You can also set this a a deployment option under the project properties. The value should be set to "do not process".